# Can not start mysql server

Tags: mysql, freebsd

I got the problem with starting my mysql server, it was working fine until I copied the "ready" mysql configuration file (`/usr/local/share/mysql/my-huge.cnf`) to the `/etc/my.cnf`, then I restarted my mysql server and unfortunatelly it stopped , instead of restarted.

I dont have any console errors, but this appear in my `/var/db/mysql/hostname.pid` file:

```
120312 17:57:43 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/hostname.pid ended
120312 17:58:09 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/db/mysql
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
120312 17:58:09 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
120312 17:58:09  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
120312 17:58:09  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 34387018176 in file fsp0fsp.c line 2040
InnoDB: Failing assertion: inode
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
17:58:09 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed, 
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=8388608
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to 
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 338444 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

120312 17:58:09 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/db/mysql/hostname.pid ended
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: back the old cnf file. The configuration of your server does not match with your my-huge.cnf - I got a similar error with linux when try to backup my server from ib_data files. MyISAM works fine, but innodb does not, 'cause it uses other files to compose your tables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ibdata file is the wrong size.

More exactly, your ibdata file is a different file size from what you have specified in the new my.cnf file. Check the values for ibdata (and bin log files, while you're at it) in the old and new versions of the my.cnf files - you'll see they're different.

You will *have* to use the old values to get the db to start; check other innodb values in there as well: make all the significant ones the same (you'll change them back after you get it working). Once you've got it started, dump your dbs and then shutdown mysqld. Edit the my.cnf file, delete ibdata, restart the db, and re-import your dbs. Presto - fixed.

Comment: Well, its very strange because when I'm removing the log files, `ibdata` file, and finally `my.cnf` file... mysql is staring, but why it does start with NO config? When I place ANY configuration file in the `/etc`, there are problems...

Comment: If there's no config file, mysqld starts with all default values, so that's why it's okay with no config file. I think you should be okay with this sequence of tasks: backup (because you have data in ibdata file), delete ibdata and ib_logfile[01], set the config you want, start - and you'll have it working. Reload your data and you'll be all set.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your my.cnf file is bad or has some bad entries in it. Do you have a copy of the my.cnf you replaced with my-huge.cnf? I would try running a diff on the two files and see what is going on.

Comment: Its not my own `my.cnf` file - its read to use file which appears after mysql installation, by default, there was no `my.cnf` file in `/etc/` BUT mysql server worked! Then I copied the sample file there and problems started, also tried to remove this file and start mysql server - no results, also tried to replace this cnf file with one I'm using on another server - but it still doesn't start...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Innodb logs are corrupt. You should backup renaming this logs and restart mysqld again, then mysqld creates the new logs and hopefully restart correctly.